# cleditor Add text cursor position textarea

Tags: text, cursor, position, addition, cleditor

I'm using the clEditor control and I need to add text at cursor position in textarea when I selected an item in a select control.

Somebody can help me, please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This code will add text from variable `text_to_add` at cursor position :

```
var text_to_add = 'Welcome to Senegal !';
var editor = $('.my_textarea').cleditor()[0];
editor.focus();
setTimeout(function() {
    editor.execCommand('inserthtml', text_to_add, false);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Do you know, what to do, if the cursor is on text, which is wrapped in a tag? Here's an example, how it works for me. Initial Cleditor content: `<font>FooBarBaz</font>`. After your code: `<font>FooB</font>Welcome to Senegal !<font>arBaz</font>`.

Comment: `inserthtml` command will add any HTML text, so with `<font>FooBarBaz</font>` it will work fine.